# HMI lost connectivity to TCP ip network

Tags: ethernet, tcp-ip, hmi

I need help with an ASEM HMI130TF with a SCADA program on it works on Windows 7. it is connected with LAN network TCP/ip with a PLC and another HMI, and it has a static ip.

the problem is it sometimes loses connectivity to this LAN, thus it can't send or get commands from PLC, I don't know why. I tested the cable and every other element and they are all ok.

I tried to connect it to the internet directly and it worked perfectly. but it doesn't want to connect to the LAN.
can you help me?s

Comment: Searching that part number brings up nothing, but you should contact the manufacturer for support. I'm a software engineer who deals primarily with automation equipment and I've never encountered that part number before. It's possible you have a bad port on the switch or your cable is run incorrectly with high power lines, those are the things I encounter most often.

Comment: i edited it, the company called ASEM, this is the link http://www.asem.it/en/products/industrial-automation/hmi-solutions/hmi30/

Comment: as i said it can't be a bad port as it works fine with the internet but not with the LAN and there isn't really any high power lines there everything is separated.